# SQL Getting Running Count with SUM and OVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

In sql I have a history table for each item we have and they can have a record of in or out with a quantity for each action. I'm trying to get a running count of how many of an item we have based on whether it's an activity of out or in. Here is my final sql:

```
SELECT itemid,
       activitydate,
       activitycode,
       SUM(quantity) AS quantity,
       SUM(CASE WHEN activitycode = 'IN'
           THEN quantity
           WHEN activitycode = 'OUT'
           THEN -quantity
           ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY activitydate rows unbounded preceding) AS runningcount
FROM   itemhistory
GROUP BY itemid,
         activitydate,
         activitycode
```

This results in:

```
+--------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
| itemid |      activitydate       | activitycode | quantity | runningcount |
+--------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
|      1 | 2017-06-08 13:58:00.000 | IN           |        1 |            1 |
|      1 | 2017-06-08 16:02:00.000 | IN           |        6 |            2 |
|      1 | 2017-06-15 11:43:00.000 | OUT          |        3 |            1 |
|      1 | 2017-06-19 12:36:00.000 | IN           |        1 |            2 |
|      2 | 2017-06-08 13:50:00.000 | IN           |        5 |            1 |
|      2 | 2017-06-12 12:41:00.000 | IN           |        4 |            2 |
|      2 | 2017-06-15 11:38:00.000 | OUT          |        2 |            1 |
|      2 | 2017-06-20 12:54:00.000 | IN           |       15 |            2 |
|      2 | 2017-06-08 13:52:00.000 | IN           |        5 |            3 |
|      2 | 2017-06-12 13:09:00.000 | IN           |        1 |            4 |
|      2 | 2017-06-15 11:47:00.000 | OUT          |        1 |            3 |
|      2 | 2017-06-20 13:14:00.000 | IN           |        1 |            4 |
+--------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
```

I want the end result to look like this:

```
+--------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
| itemid |      activitydate       | activitycode | quantity | runningcount |
+--------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
|      1 | 2017-06-08 13:58:00.000 | IN           |        1 |            1 |
|      1 | 2017-06-08 16:02:00.000 | IN           |        6 |            7 |
|      1 | 2017-06-15 11:43:00.000 | OUT          |        3 |            4 |
|      1 | 2017-06-19 12:36:00.000 | IN           |        1 |            5 |
|      2 | 2017-06-08 13:50:00.000 | IN           |        5 |            5 |
|      2 | 2017-06-12 12:41:00.000 | IN           |        4 |            9 |
|      2 | 2017-06-15 11:38:00.000 | OUT          |        2 |            7 |
|      2 | 2017-06-20 12:54:00.000 | IN           |       15 |           22 |
|      2 | 2017-06-08 13:52:00.000 | IN           |        5 |           27 |
|      2 | 2017-06-12 13:09:00.000 | IN           |        1 |           28 |
|      2 | 2017-06-15 11:47:00.000 | OUT          |        1 |           27 |
|      2 | 2017-06-20 13:14:00.000 | IN           |        1 |           28 |
+--------+-------------------------+--------------+----------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `sum(sum())`, because this is an aggregation query:

```
SELECT itemid, activitydate, activitycode,
       SUM(quantity) AS quantity,
       SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN activitycode = 'IN' THEN quantity
                    WHEN activitycode = 'OUT' THEN -quantity
                    ELSE 0
               END)
           ) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY activitydate ) AS runningcount
FROM itemhistory
GROUP BY itemid, activitydate, activitycode
```